# Inspecting ZooKeeper's state as it is running

Tags: java, apache, telnet, apache-zookeeper, jconsole

So far the only way I know how to inspect the state of my zookeeper instance is by running this code in my client:

```
for(String w: zk.getChildren("/workers", false))
{
    System.out.println("Worker:" + w);
}
```

Is there a way I can do this outside of my program at will? I would like to be able to see a complete listing or picture of my zookeeper state. The four letter word command dump does not list persistent nodes and when using jconsole, I can see my zookeeoer servers, but not the nodes. In my O'Reilly zookeeper book and online I cannot find a way to inspect zookeeper's state, let me know if you know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`zkCli`](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_ConnectingToZooKeeper) tool (`zkCli.sh` or `zkCli.bat`) to query Zookeeper from the command line.  It is covered in the O'Reilly book - see the index.

You can also use the `ZooInspector` tool that is in the Zookeeper contrib directory.